# If the roots of the equation $x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0$ are in geometric progression then,

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

If the roots of the equation $x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0$ are in geometric progression then,

$a) b^2 = ac$

$b) a^2 = b$

$c) c^2 = a^2d$

Using Vieta's relations, finding values of coefficients in terms of the assumed roots is what first comes to mind. That process works out well to give the answer ($c)$) But, as it can be seen, this method is quite lengthy. Is there a shorter method to solve this question or a trick?

Comment: Try assuming the roots are $a, ar, ar^2, ar^3$

Comment: @xxxx036 Thanks for that. The answer is easily obtained by that method as I mentioned. However, is there a shorter method? This one is quite lengthy.

Comment: In hindsight, you would only need to calculate $a$ and $c$, but it's hard to justify unless you already know the answer.

Comment: @TobyMak Exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: let the roots be $t,u,v,w$, then a sufficient condition for a GP is $tw=uv$ $\implies tw=uv=\sqrt{tuvw}=\sqrt{d}$.

This requires $d\gt 0$, and in that case let $x=x'\sqrt[4]{d}$ then the polynomial

$$dx'^4+a\sqrt[4]{d^3} x'^3+b\sqrt{d} x'^2+c\sqrt[4]{d} x' +d $$

has roots $t'=t/\sqrt[4]{d}, u'=u/\sqrt[4]{d},\dots$ with $t'w'=u'v'=1$ i.e. it is [reciprocal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial), so $a\sqrt[4]{d^3}=c\sqrt[4]{d}\,$.

Comment: That was elegant!

Comment: @mathx This does not even require the full premise of a GP, but just that the two pairs of roots have the same ratio $u/t=w/v$.

Comment: Oh Yes. Nice observation.

Comment: For an example, $x^4 - 24 x^3 + 163 x^2 - 336 x + 196$ has roots $1,2,7,14$ which are not in a GP, but $2/1 = 14/7$ and indeed $336^2 = 24^2 * 196$.

Comment: OK. Before posting the question, I was thinking if some coefficient substitution could make the solution shorter. How did you come up with that equation? It seems difficult to create something like that.

Comment: @mathx A GP with geometric mean $1$ is invariant to the transformation $\,x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}\,$, so the first step "normalizes" the GP such that it has geometric mean $\,1\,$. Then, a polynomial invariant to the transformation $\,x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}\,$ must have the symmetric coefficients equal, so the result follows.

Comment: dxiv OK. Got it.

Comment: @mathx Loosely related, see an example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2137432/291201) of *additive* symmetry, where the pairwise sums are equal (instead of their products). In that case, what simplifies the problem is a translation $\,x \mapsto x-x_0\,$ which brings the mean to zero.

Comment: That one is a clever solution too. Immensely appreciate it. Really nice and elegant!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the OP's original method. Assume the roots are $k, kr, kr^2, kr^3$. Then:

$$k(1+r+r^2+r^3) = -a$$
$$k^2r+k^2r^3+k^2r^4+k^2r^3+k^2r^4+k^3r^5 = b$$
$$k^3r^3 + k^3r^4+k^3r^5+k^3r^6 = k^3 r^3(1+r+r^2+r^3) = -c$$
$$k^4r^6 = d$$

By comparing the maximum powers of $r$, a) is not correct ($r^{10}$ vs $r^9$) and so is b). But $c/a = k^2r^3$ or $c^2/a^2 = k^4r^6 = d$, hence c) is correct.

This relationship between $a$ and $c$ can be extended to any power $n$ in general. $-c$ can also be written as $k^4 r^6 (1/k + 1/(kr) + 1/(kr^2) + 1/(kr^3))$ as you miss out one term in the product of three (or $n$) roots, and in general this is $k^n r^{n(n-1)/2} (1/k + \cdots + \frac{1}{kr^{n-1}}) = k^{n-1} r^{(n-1)(n-2)/2} (1 + \cdots + r^{n-1})$.

Comment: What is $r^{10}$ vs $r^9$ point to?

Comment: The highest power of $b$ is $r^5$, hence the highest power of $b^2$ is $r^{10}$. Similarly, the highest power of $r$ in $ac$ is $r^3 \cdot r^6 = r^9$.

Comment: Your answer is as clever as that of dxiv

Comment: @mathx Thank you!